# Passing Value in StoryBoard

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uistoryboardsegue

I want to pass value in storyboard by init in storyboard . This code used in xib working well. But in storyboard my application crash. This is my Code snippets Please help Any help would be appreciated.

In FirstviewController

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
        viewControllerd = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("a") as? SecondViewController
        viewControllerd = SecondViewController.init(title: "helo")
        addViewControllerAsChildViewController(viewControllerd!)
```

SecondView Controller

```
        init(title : String)
        {
            a = title
            super.init(nibName: "SecondViewController", bundle: nil)
        }

        required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
        {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
        }
```

Comment: Please show the crash log.

Answer (score 0):

```
viewControllerd = SecondViewController.init(title: "helo")
```

replace code with

```
viewControllerd.title = "helo"
```

and not need following code :

```
init(title : String){

    a = title
     super.init(nibName: "SecondViewController", bundle: nil)

}
```

Comment: Than create date variable in SecondViewController class and pass like following : viewControllerd.date = Date()

Comment: or replace init(title : String, date:Date){

    a = title
     super.init(nibName: "SecondViewController", bundle: nil)

}

Answer (score 0):

You have a mess in your code.
Probably the app crashes due to double setting to `viewControllerd`.
It is defined as constant (`let`) but you set a value to it twice: `viewControllerd = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("a") as? SecondViewController` and `viewControllerd = SecondViewController.init(title: "helo")`.

In addition, the `super.init(nibName: "SecondViewController", bundle: nil)` is irrelevant when you work with storyboard.
`init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)` is called when you instantiate a view controller from storyboard and you can just pass a value to it.

What you can do is set a value to newly created view controller's property.
E.g.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
let viewControllerd = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("a") as? SecondViewController
viewControllerd.a = "helo"
addViewControllerAsChildViewController(viewControllerd!)
```

Comment: Sir can we do not pass value with init just we do in xib

Comment: @Rishab I didn't understand your comment. You can't pass an argument from code to a view controller that is instantiated from storyboard.

Comment: Once again, you can pass an argument by setting a value to some property.